# Offset vertical position of a child of a RelativeLayout which is vertically centered

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/ft_graph_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bar_graph_pager_height"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ft_rsvp_graph_indicator"/>
```

Which is a child of a RelativeLayout. Behind this ViewPager is a 9patch image representing the lines of a graph.

The content of the ViewPager should line up with the 9patch graph lines, but I can't just make them the same height and call it a day because the ViewPager contents have a caption which should be positioned below the graph lines.

With the XML above, this is what it looks like:

[image]

I'm super close. As you can see, if I can just get the ViewPager's contents (the bar graph items and **San Diego** below) to shift down slightly I'm in business.

The first thing I tried to do is set `layout_marginBottom="-6dp"` which did nothing.

Then I tried to set `paddingBottom="-6dp"` which also did nothing.

Setting `paddingTop="6dp"` doesn't do anything either, but setting the bottom padding to a positive number DOES have an affect, even though it is completely unhelpful for me.

The RelativeLayout parent for this Pager and 9patch contains another view as well, one which is larger than both and hinges on the 9patch being perfectly vertically centered, so I can't make the 9patch move instead.

The full contents of the RelativeLayout are below:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ft_bar_graph_indicator"
                  android:layout_width="@dimen/bar_graph_indicator_width"
                  android:layout_height="@dimen/bar_graph_indicator_height"
                  android:orientation="vertical">

       <!--TODO fill-->

    </LinearLayout>

    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/bar_graph_height"
          android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ft_bar_graph_indicator"
          android:background="@drawable/graph_lines"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/ft_graph_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bar_graph_pager_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ft_rsvp_graph_indicator"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was unable to figure out how to do this via XML, so if someone is able to do that go ahead and post it and I will make that the official answer.

However I was able to come up with a work around in Java. When I declared my ViewPager in my Activity, I just added this:

```
Display display = mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
display.getMetrics(metrics);
ViewHelper.setTranslationY(mGraphPager, 5 * metrics.density);
```

5 being the dp I ended up shifting it down. ViewHelper is part of the [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) library, which helps simulate methods from the View class added in API 11+